# Iterating over a python list gives different result

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am having some problem with lists in python.
I have a list of objects I get from a call to an API (facebook ads). When I print it's length, it is 25, but when I iterate over it using:

```
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

I get 40 elements. Since I need to iterate over the 40 elements to find if some are missing I need to find a way to keep this list (so I can't use for i in lst) but I cant use it's length since I don't have all items with this method.

Any idea on how to fix this and why does this happen (I am using python 3.6)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide a *verifiable* example. Without it we can't really know what is going on.

Comment: Are you sure your `lst` is really a list? Maybe it is a strange iterator, with a different `__len__` method. If it is the case, you can cast it to a list by making `list_lst = list(lst)`

Comment: @eqperes You were right, it's actually a 'facebookads.api.Cursor'. Casting it to a list solved the problem. Thanks a lot.